# A word that encompasses buying and selling?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, hypernyms

I'm trying to retag some questions (such as [this one](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/573/2133)) on the Board Game Stack Exchange, and the only good tag I can think of is "Selling".

But that seems inefficient, and a word that covers both *buying* and *selling* would be more useful to the site. The first word I thought of was *transaction* but that doesn't seem to cover it.

Someone has suggested to me *business*, but again it doesn't sound like it works in the context.

Is there not a single word (or a phrase shorter than 25 characters) for this?

Comment: How about trading?

Comment: Maybe "Commerce".

Comment: Does that cover selling/buying with money? It feels more like it is more suited to swapping one item for another.

Comment: **WTO** = World Trade Organization. The people who buy and sell stocks for a living at the NY Stock Exchange are called **traders**, not swappers.

Comment: WTO would be traitors, not traders. ;)

Comment: What about market transactions ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My first thought when I saw “buying and selling” was **[trading](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/trade?s=t)** (independently of [coleopterist](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88247/a-word-that-encompasses-buying-and-selling#comment176821_88247). The verb *trade* covers both bartering (trading when both parties put forth goods or services) and buying/selling (trading when one of the parties puts forth money).

In context, this seems to be specifically about evaluating the price. I believe the term generally used in this domain is *appraisal*; *valuation* or *pricing* are used with a similar meaning in other communities.

Comment: *Appraisal* has a nice ring to it.

Answer (score 0):

The word you seek is 'commerce'.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: Hi LLD. This is a good answer, but, as the OP has mentioned, it would be best accompanied by a cited dictionary definition.

Answer (score -2):

*Arbitrage* may be the word you are looking for.

Comment: *Arbitrage* seems to encompass more than just buying and selling.

Comment: And also to not cover much that is covered by buying and selling either.

Answer (score -2):

The role of [*procurement*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/procurement) (one of the professional terms for purchasing and selling) is to find a sustainable supply of goods at a reasonable price.